# Iterate through records in view and create text_fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table: `family_children` (the model is `family_child`) where family has many children.

I get the children like this:

```
@family_children = @family.children
```

where `.children` is an association to `family_children` table.

In a view I want to iterate through the children, and put each of them in a text_field. Of course, I need these fields as params when the page is POSTing. I.e. I think that I should get the children as an array.

How can I achieve that?

I mean, if I'll write

```
<%= text_field 'child', 'name' %>
```

I don't really get what I need.

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more information? Which form you want to add those fields, I mean in the family form or somewhere else?  how do you want to access them in controller etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your view:

```
<% @family_children.each_with_index do |c, i| %>
  <%= text_field_tag "children[#{i}]", c.name %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

This should return params[:children] after posting which should be an array. I wasn't sure of the name of the property you want to show in the text box so I have assumed it is called 'name'.

Comment: The HTML that I get: '<input type="text" value="child 1" name="child[#{i}]" id="child___i_">'. Why are all the underlines? and why do I get the i and not the number? Is that the output that you intended?

Comment: Sorry - put single quotes when I intend double quotes. Have edited my answer, should now produce a name attribute that looks like: name="children[1]"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `@family_children` object acts as array, so you can simply call `each` or `map` on it.

Comment: But how should the text_field look like?

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Look at the end of my question again, please

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to put the `children`'s names in a form field or in the view as just a part of the page text?  could you include the view file?

Answer (score 0):

since u want the family_children data to be POSTed, u need to see the concept of nested attributes. please see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html and http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

```
class Family
  has_many :children, :class => "FamilyChild"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

class FamilyChild
  belongs_to :family
end
```

and the form can be as

```
<%= form_for @family do |p| %>
  First name: <%= p.text_field :first_name %>
  Last name : <%= p.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= fields_for @family.children do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :child_name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```